# Python round with `n // 1`

Tags: python, division, integer-division

I was wondering if there is any reason not to use the `//` operator to round a number to an integer. I didn't see much on this topic or really know what to look for to find out more.

```
>>> from random import random
>>> random() * 20 // 1
1.0
>>> random() * 20 // 1
0.0
>>> random() * 20 // 1
16.0
>>> random() * 20 // 1
11.0
>>> random() * 20 // 1
0.0
```

Besides needing to add 1 to the result (to not get a range of 1-20 instead of 0-19) Or does this actual result in the range 0-20?

Comment: You should use `int` to convert `float` to `int`, and use `random.randrange` to generate `int`.

Comment: Like `range`, `random` is *half-open*; it doesn't include `1.0`, so you will never get `20`. If you want random integers, why not `random.choice`, `.randrange` or `.randint`?

Comment: The [`//` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) doesn't round to the nearest integer, it does [floor division](http://python-history.blogspot.ch/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Answer (score 3):

The main reason not to use it would be that there are perfectly good in-built functions `int` and `round` that already do this, which are likely to be efficient and will not confuse someone reading your code.

Another reason as pointed out in the comments is that `//1` is equivalent to `math.floor` rather than `int` or `round`. `-2.5 // 1` returns a float `-3.0` whereas `int(-2.5)` returns an integer `-2`.

The fact that experienced programmers can be confused about what `//1` does, illustrates nicely why it is better to use one of the existing functions designed for this purpose -- they behave in ways that are clearly defined, documented and consistent.

Answer (score 3):

The reason not to use `//` to convert a random float to a random int is because you can skip straight to the random int:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.random()      # [0.0, 1.0)
0.4399641241469895
>>> random.uniform(0,20) # [0.0, 20.0)
11.494311814130072
>>> random.randint(0,20) # [0, 20) or [0, 19]
7
```

To answer your question: `x // y` performs a floor division of x by y, so your result will always round down.  To round to the closest integer:

```
>>> x = 1.7
>>> x // 1
1.0
>>> int(x)
1
>>> (x + 0.5) // 1
2.0
>>> int(x + 0.5)
2
>>> round(x)
2.0
>>> int(round(x))
2
```

Adding 0.5 (or subtracting for a negative number) before converting to an int does the same thing as `round(x)` (built-in).  It's worth noting that `x // 1` rounds down, but `int(x)` round toward zero.

It is not possible for `random.random() * 20 // 1` to return 20 because random is half-open.  `random.uniform(0,20) // 1`, however, can return 20, but the chance of that happening is near-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [`//`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) does not round an integer. Round means to return the closest integer, but check this:

```
print round(1.9)     # 2.0
print 1.9 // 1       # 1.0
```

Comment: So its more approximate to the `floor` function. I may liberally misuse the word round to myself to mean any float to integer conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a range of `0-19` and `//` is in fact floor division that still yields a floating point number but I read this is what you meant to say.

A possible reason not to use may be that `// 1` is not a very concise syntax for expressing it. Python is highly about readability, and this syntax is not very obvious to what it does. It is like JavaScript's `~~x` trick.

*If I were to review this code*, I would suspect a bug first and a feature second.